# Finding the coordinates of cubes or hypercubes in n-dimensional space using NumPy meshgrid

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So I can't seem to cross the finish line on a problem I am having.
I am trying to define a n-dimensional coordinate space then partition this space into a k**d set of d-dimensional cells where d is the dimensionality and k is the number of bins being used to partition the axes.
If I generate a set of boundaries for the cells using the following:

```
points = []
n_bins = 3
for dim in range(3):
    boundary = np.linspace(0, 2, n_bins+1)
    points.append(boundary)
```

For a 3-dimensional problem this is repeated three times in a for loop as in actuality each of the dimensions has a different range to be binned.
Then the meshgrid is created as follows:

```
points = np.array(points)
grid = np.stack(np.meshgrid(*points)).T
```

This appears to generate the necessary combinations of points that can be used to find the coordinates of each cube as illustrated below. However, I am completely stuck on how to extract the coordinates of the 9 cubes for this example case.

Since I am stuck on this simpler problem I can't even begin to tackle how to extract the coordinates of the hypercubes in a higher dimensional space.
Would anyone be able to provide some assistance on this?
Apologies if I have not provided enough detail.

```
[[[[0. 0. 0.]
   [0. 1. 0.]
   [0. 2. 0.]
   [0. 3. 0.]]

  [[1. 0. 0.]
   [1. 1. 0.]
   [1. 2. 0.]
   [1. 3. 0.]]

  [[2. 0. 0.]
   [2. 1. 0.]
   [2. 2. 0.]
   [2. 3. 0.]]

  [[3. 0. 0.]
   [3. 1. 0.]
   [3. 2. 0.]
   [3. 3. 0.]]]


 [[[0. 0. 1.]
   [0. 1. 1.]
   [0. 2. 1.]
   [0. 3. 1.]]

  [[1. 0. 1.]
   [1. 1. 1.]
   [1. 2. 1.]
   [1. 3. 1.]]

  [[2. 0. 1.]
   [2. 1. 1.]
   [2. 2. 1.]
   [2. 3. 1.]]

  [[3. 0. 1.]
   [3. 1. 1.]
   [3. 2. 1.]
   [3. 3. 1.]]]


 [[[0. 0. 2.]
   [0. 1. 2.]
   [0. 2. 2.]
   [0. 3. 2.]]

  [[1. 0. 2.]
   [1. 1. 2.]
   [1. 2. 2.]
   [1. 3. 2.]]

  [[2. 0. 2.]
   [2. 1. 2.]
   [2. 2. 2.]
   [2. 3. 2.]]

  [[3. 0. 2.]
   [3. 1. 2.]
   [3. 2. 2.]
   [3. 3. 2.]]]


 [[[0. 0. 3.]
   [0. 1. 3.]
   [0. 2. 3.]
   [0. 3. 3.]]

  [[1. 0. 3.]
   [1. 1. 3.]
   [1. 2. 3.]
   [1. 3. 3.]]

  [[2. 0. 3.]
   [2. 1. 3.]
   [2. 2. 3.]
   [2. 3. 3.]]

  [[3. 0. 3.]
   [3. 1. 3.]
   [3. 2. 3.]
   [3. 3. 3.]]]]
```

Comment: What are you going to do with this information?  The problem with meshgrid is that it quickly gets very, very large.  It gives you a list of EVERY POINT within the volume of the cube/hypercube.

Comment: @TimRoberts thank you for your comment! The general idea is that at most I will be generating 3^5 (264) or 5^3 (125) cubes/hypercubes due to that exponential increase in cell count. The centre of each of those cubes/hypercubes will become a representative point similar to k-means cluster centroids.
So, I guess you could say I am looking for a solution for a very selective set of parameters really i.e. k = 3, 5 and d = 3, 5.
I hope this answers your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, third times the charm.

I produce a list of the split points on each axis. For an 8 cube in 3 parts, that produces `[0,3,6,8]`.  I then do an offset zip of that list to produce the begin/end points: `[0,3],[3,6],[6,8]]`

All combinations of those three things produce the set of cubes.  Printing the coordinates is then just a matter of another `product` to combine the start and end points:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
cube = 8
n_bins = 3

pts = list(range(0,cube,n_bins)) + [cube]
print(pts)
pairs = list(zip(pts[:-1],pts[1:]))
print(pairs)


for p1 in itertools.product( *([pairs]*3) ):
    print("Subcube:")
    for p2 in itertools.product(*p1):
        print(p2)
```

Output:

```
[0, 3, 6, 8]
[(0, 3), (3, 6), (6, 8)]
Subcube:
(0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 3)
(0, 3, 0)
(0, 3, 3)
(3, 0, 0)
(3, 0, 3)
(3, 3, 0)
(3, 3, 3)
Subcube:
(0, 0, 3)
(0, 0, 6)
(0, 3, 3)
(0, 3, 6)
(3, 0, 3)
(3, 0, 6)
(3, 3, 3)
(3, 3, 6)
Subcube:
(0, 0, 6)
(0, 0, 8)
(0, 3, 6)
(0, 3, 8)
(3, 0, 6)
(3, 0, 8)
(3, 3, 6)
(3, 3, 8)
Subcube:
(0, 3, 0)
(0, 3, 3)
(0, 6, 0)
(0, 6, 3)
(3, 3, 0)
(3, 3, 3)
(3, 6, 0)
(3, 6, 3)
Subcube:
(0, 3, 3)
(0, 3, 6)
(0, 6, 3)
(0, 6, 6)
(3, 3, 3)
(3, 3, 6)
(3, 6, 3)
(3, 6, 6)
Subcube:
(0, 3, 6)
(0, 3, 8)
(0, 6, 6)
(0, 6, 8)
(3, 3, 6)
(3, 3, 8)
(3, 6, 6)
(3, 6, 8)
Subcube:
(0, 6, 0)
(0, 6, 3)
(0, 8, 0)
(0, 8, 3)
(3, 6, 0)
(3, 6, 3)
(3, 8, 0)
(3, 8, 3)
Subcube:
(0, 6, 3)
(0, 6, 6)
(0, 8, 3)
(0, 8, 6)
(3, 6, 3)
(3, 6, 6)
(3, 8, 3)
(3, 8, 6)
Subcube:
(0, 6, 6)
(0, 6, 8)
(0, 8, 6)
(0, 8, 8)
(3, 6, 6)
(3, 6, 8)
(3, 8, 6)
(3, 8, 8)
Subcube:
(3, 0, 0)
(3, 0, 3)
(3, 3, 0)
(3, 3, 3)
(6, 0, 0)
(6, 0, 3)
(6, 3, 0)
(6, 3, 3)
Subcube:
(3, 0, 3)
(3, 0, 6)
(3, 3, 3)
(3, 3, 6)
(6, 0, 3)
(6, 0, 6)
(6, 3, 3)
(6, 3, 6)
Subcube:
(3, 0, 6)
(3, 0, 8)
(3, 3, 6)
(3, 3, 8)
(6, 0, 6)
(6, 0, 8)
(6, 3, 6)
(6, 3, 8)
Subcube:
(3, 3, 0)
(3, 3, 3)
(3, 6, 0)
(3, 6, 3)
(6, 3, 0)
(6, 3, 3)
(6, 6, 0)
(6, 6, 3)
Subcube:
(3, 3, 3)
(3, 3, 6)
(3, 6, 3)
(3, 6, 6)
(6, 3, 3)
(6, 3, 6)
(6, 6, 3)
(6, 6, 6)
Subcube:
(3, 3, 6)
(3, 3, 8)
(3, 6, 6)
(3, 6, 8)
(6, 3, 6)
(6, 3, 8)
(6, 6, 6)
(6, 6, 8)
Subcube:
(3, 6, 0)
(3, 6, 3)
(3, 8, 0)
(3, 8, 3)
(6, 6, 0)
(6, 6, 3)
(6, 8, 0)
(6, 8, 3)
Subcube:
(3, 6, 3)
(3, 6, 6)
(3, 8, 3)
(3, 8, 6)
(6, 6, 3)
(6, 6, 6)
(6, 8, 3)
(6, 8, 6)
Subcube:
(3, 6, 6)
(3, 6, 8)
(3, 8, 6)
(3, 8, 8)
(6, 6, 6)
(6, 6, 8)
(6, 8, 6)
(6, 8, 8)
Subcube:
(6, 0, 0)
(6, 0, 3)
(6, 3, 0)
(6, 3, 3)
(8, 0, 0)
(8, 0, 3)
(8, 3, 0)
(8, 3, 3)
Subcube:
(6, 0, 3)
(6, 0, 6)
(6, 3, 3)
(6, 3, 6)
(8, 0, 3)
(8, 0, 6)
(8, 3, 3)
(8, 3, 6)
Subcube:
(6, 0, 6)
(6, 0, 8)
(6, 3, 6)
(6, 3, 8)
(8, 0, 6)
(8, 0, 8)
(8, 3, 6)
(8, 3, 8)
Subcube:
(6, 3, 0)
(6, 3, 3)
(6, 6, 0)
(6, 6, 3)
(8, 3, 0)
(8, 3, 3)
(8, 6, 0)
(8, 6, 3)
Subcube:
(6, 3, 3)
(6, 3, 6)
(6, 6, 3)
(6, 6, 6)
(8, 3, 3)
(8, 3, 6)
(8, 6, 3)
(8, 6, 6)
Subcube:
(6, 3, 6)
(6, 3, 8)
(6, 6, 6)
(6, 6, 8)
(8, 3, 6)
(8, 3, 8)
(8, 6, 6)
(8, 6, 8)
Subcube:
(6, 6, 0)
(6, 6, 3)
(6, 8, 0)
(6, 8, 3)
(8, 6, 0)
(8, 6, 3)
(8, 8, 0)
(8, 8, 3)
Subcube:
(6, 6, 3)
(6, 6, 6)
(6, 8, 3)
(6, 8, 6)
(8, 6, 3)
(8, 6, 6)
(8, 8, 3)
(8, 8, 6)
Subcube:
(6, 6, 6)
(6, 6, 8)
(6, 8, 6)
(6, 8, 8)
(8, 6, 6)
(8, 6, 8)
(8, 8, 6)
(8, 8, 8)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Sorry I should have added some additional context in my question. The points listed in the meshgrid output are the vertices of the cells. I just need to collate the vertices of the cubes together into separate arrays. For instance, the first cube in a 3D space would be a list containing (0,0,0) (0,0,1) (0,1,0) (0,1,1) (1,0,0) (1,1,0) (1,0,1) (1,1,1) if that makes sense? Sorry for any confusion caused.

Comment: So, how do you want to split the fractions?  Dividing a 5-edge into 3 pieces produces fractional coordinates.

Comment: Hi Tim. Apologies if there has been some confusion. It is just the set of cube face vertices that I am after as opposed to edge coordinates. If the coordinates in my previous comment correspond to the vertices of the first cube then the next cube along the x-axis would be defined by the set: (1,1,1) (1,1,0) (1,0,1) (1,0,0) (2,0,0) (2,0,1) (2,1,0) (2,1,1). Where the first 4 coordinates correspond to a face of the first cube. So each subcube will be defined by just 8 coordinates.

Comment: That's what I gave you the first time -- the corner vertex positions.

Comment: Ahhh okay really sorry about that. I couldn't work out if the original answer had listed the vertex positions which is what meshgrid has also done. Or if you had managed to organise the coordinates so that you would have 9 separate sets of 8 points representing the individual cubes which is what I am aiming for. Was the original answer producing the latter? Again apologies if I had misinterpreted your original answer!

Comment: What I show now is 9 sets of 8 points.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate this. Much cleaner then the solution I was trying to brute force.